# Unable to run gcp_compute plugin for ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Can someone please help to resolve the below issue

Set the IAM role as editor with the same email as the service account used in the inventory yaml file .

pip- V :
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

python --version :
Python 2.7.17

OS :
Ubuntu 18.04

ansible --version :
ansible 2.5.1

Getting the below error when trying to execute the below code :

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - <project_id>
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: <path to service account JSON>
keyed_groups:
  - key: labels
    prefix: goog-gke-node
  - key: zone
    prefix: zone
groups:
   development: "'goog-gke-node' in (labels|list)"
   staging: "'squid-proxy' in name"
```

Upon running ansible-doc -t inventory -l : below is the result

```
advanced_host_list Parses a 'host list' with ranges
auto               Loads and executes an inventory plugin specified in a YAML config
aws_ec2            ec2 inventory source
constructed        Uses Jinja2 to construct vars and groups based on existing inventory.
host_list          Parses a 'host list' string
ini                Uses an Ansible INI file as inventory source.
k8s                Kubernetes (K8s) inventory source
openshift          OpenShift inventory source
openstack          OpenStack inventory source
script             Executes an inventory script that returns JSON
virtualbox         virtualbox inventory source
yaml               Uses a specifically YAML file as inventory source.
```

And ansible-doc -t inventory gcp_compute would give the below message.

```
 [WARNING]: inventory gcp_compute not found in: /home/nishchaldinesh/.ansible/plugins/inventory:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/inventory:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/ansible/plugins/inventory
```

Output error when running the gcp.yaml file : ansible-inventory --list -i gcp_test.yaml

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp_test.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory

 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp_test.yaml with constructed plugin: Incorrect plugin name in file: aws_ec2

 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp_test.yaml as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {}
}
```

Comment: Ansible 2.5.1 is over 3 years old (about dino Era relative to its development pace). Please upgrade to a recent version (at least 2.9 and preferably >= 2.10 if possible). Meanwhile, regarding your above error, it does not match with the content you are showing (i.e. `Incorrect plugin name in file: aws_ec2`). Moreover, your file name does not respect the naming convention. From [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/gcp_compute.html): `Uses a YAML configuration file that ends with gcp_compute.(yml|yaml) or gcp.(yml|yaml)` (please note the **ends with**)

Comment: I suggested to upgrade above as a general good practice. Looking arround a bit more, you'll find that the `gcp_compute` inventory plugin was [added in ansible version 2.6](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.6/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.6.rst#inventory) (and is now part of the [google.cloud collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/google.cloud) when using ansible >= 2.10)

Comment: @Zeitounator., Updating the Ansible resolved the issue. Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the ansible version above 2.9.6 resolved the issue..